Probability distribution of sum of many differently weighted coins
Imagine that we have $100$ coins, which each have a random weight between $0$ and $1$ $\left(~\mbox{but we know the weights}~\right)$:

That is to say, we have $100$ known numbers $p_{1}, p_{2},\ldots, p_{100} \in \left[0, 1\right]$ such that

coin $n$ has probability $p_{n}$ of flipping heads, which we treat as
an outcome of $1$,
and probability $1 - p_{n}$ of flipping tails,
which we treat as an outcome of $0$.


We want the probability distribution of the sum of these $100$ coins. How can we compute it efficiently, exactly if possible or approximately if not possible $?$.


The normal approximation would work well here.  This would have mean equal to the sum of the $p_i$ and variance = sum of $p_i(1-p_i)$.

Thanks for your comment, @Paul. How do you compute the variance, and how do you justify the normal approximation when the random variables being summed are not identically distributed? You're certainly right; I can tell that by doing a simulation. But I don't know why you are right.

That's a tricky pair of questions, because the easiest answers have different characterizations of the distribution.  For the variance we treat the result as the sum of 100 different distributions.  Since they are independent, the variances are additive.  For the second, you can treat them as identically distributed, where the probabilities are drawn from the discrete set of 100.  They are not independent in this viewpoint, but that only affects the convergence rats, not the normal distribution parameters.

Since $100$ is a small enough number, you can compute the entire distribution exactly with the help of a computer.
More generally, say that there are $m$ coins total, with probabilities $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_m$ of heads, and you want the full probability distribution for the total number of heads. For each $k\in \{0,1,\dots,m\}$, let $q^m_k$ be the probability that there are exactly $k$ heads among the $m$ coins. You can prove that
$$
q^m_k=p_m\cdot q^{m-1}_{k-1}+(1-p_m)\cdot q^{m-1}_k\tag1
$$
This follows by conditioning on the outcome of the $m^\text{th}$ coin. Either the $m^\text{th}$ coin is heads, and you need exactly $k-1$ heads among the first $m-1$ coins, or the $m^\text{th}$ coin is tails, and you need exactly $k$ heads among the first $m-1$ coins.
Using $(1)$, you can compute $q^m_k$ for all $k\in \{0,1,\dots,m\}$ by filling out an $(m+1)\times (m+1)$ table, where the rows and columns are labeled from $0$ to $m$. The entry in the $i^\text{th}$ row and $j^\text{th}$ column should be filled with $q^i_j$, using formula $(1)$, together with the numbers in the previous row. You need to fill the rows in the order $0,1,\dots,m$, so the numbers in the previous row are available when you need them. The zeroth row is the easiest; $q^0_0=1$, while $q^0_j=0$ for all $j>0$. This takes $O(m^2)$ additions and multiplications, which is manageable by a computer when $m=100$.
There do exists faster methods. Consider a small case, say $m=4$ and $k=3$. You can show that
$$
q^4_3=p_1p_2p_3{(1-p_4)}+p_1p_2(1-p_3)p_4+p_1(1-p_2)p_3p_4+(1-p_1)p_2p_3p_4.
$$
Now, define $r_i=p_i/(1-p_i)$ for each $i\in \{1,2,3,4\}$. Then
$$
q^4_3=(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)(1-p_4)[r_1r_2r_3+r_1r_2r_4+r_1r_3r_4+r_2r_3r_4]
$$
The expression $r_1r_2r_3+r_1r_2r_4+r_1r_3r_4+r_2r_3r_4$ is known as "the third elementary symmetric polynomial in four variables", and is usually notated as $e_3(r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4)$. In general, as long as you can compute $e_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, the $k^\text{th}$ elementary symmetric polynomial in $n$ variables, then you can compute $q^n_k$. For a fast method to compute $e_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, see this Computer science stack exchange question.


We want the probability distribution of the sum of these 100
coins.

This problem is a more complicated version of the problem where $~p = p_1 = p_2 = \cdots = p_{100}.~$ For that problem, I would refer you to Binomial Distribution,
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$
In fact, if you study the binomial distribution formula, to understand its derivation, you can use your expanded intuition to develop the formula necessary for your problem.

Let $~S~$ denote any subset of $~\{1,2,\cdots,100\}.~$  So, for example, $~S~$ could be the empty set, or the entire set $~\{1,2,\cdots,100\}.$
For any such subset $~S~$ define the function $~f(S)~$ to equal
$$\left[ ~\prod_{r\in S} p_r ~\right] \times \left[ ~\prod_{r \not\in S} (1 - p_r) ~\right].$$
For $~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,100\},~$ let $~G(k)~$ denote the collection of the (exactly) $~\displaystyle \binom{100}{k}~$ subsets of $~\{1,2,\cdots,100\},~$ such that each subset in the $~G(k)~$ collection represents a subset of $~\{1,2,\cdots,100\},~$ that contains exactly $~k~$ elements.
To clarify,

$G(0)~$ contains the single subset represented by the empty set.

$G(1)~$ is the collection of all subsets of $~\{1,2,\cdots,100\},~$ that each contain exactly 1 element.

$G(2)~$ is the collection of all subsets of $~\{1,2,\cdots,100\},~$ that each contain exactly 2 elements.

And so forth.


Then, the probability distribution function, for the sum of these $~100~$ coins may be expressed as $~h(s) ~: s \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,100\},$ where $~h(s)~$ denotes the probability that the sum will equal $~s.~$  Then,
$$h(s) = \sum_{S \in G(s)} f(S).$$

Isn't this far beyond the ability of a computer to calculate (e.g. to compute $h(50)$ we need to sum over $10^{29}$ elements)?

@Zorgoth Absolutely agree.  However, the expression gives an exact answer.  I know of no analytical or computer assisted shortcut to obtaining an exact answer.

Let $n:=100$.$  \newcommand{\P}[0]{{\mathbb{P}}}$
Since we care about the convolution, one way would be probability generating functions:
The probability generating function of a bernoulli experiment with success probability $p$ is $1-p+pt$. So the convolution we care about has the probability generating function
$$F(t):=\prod_{i=1}^n (1-p_i+p_it)$$
. Let $X$ denote the random variable for the sum of the coins, then we therefore have
$$\P(X=k) = [t^k]F(t) = F^{(k)}(0)/k!$$
, i.e. we just need to find out the coefficients of the monomials of $F(t)$ if we multiply out $F(t)$, which a computer should be able to without any problems.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The $n_{th}\mbox{-coin}$ has the probability distribution $\left.\on{P}_{n}\pars{x}\right\vert_{x\ \in\ \mathbb{R}}\ =\ p_{n}\ \delta\pars{x - 1} + q_{n}\ \delta\pars{x}$ where $q_{n} \equiv 1 - p_{n}$.
Lets $\on{P}\pars{S}$ the probability distribution of the sum and $\Theta$ the Heaviside Step Function. Then,
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{\on{P}\pars{S}} & =
\color{#44f}{\totald{}{S}
\int_{0}^{S}\on{P}\pars{\xi}\,\dd\xi}
\\[5mm] & =
\totald{}{S}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ldots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{S - x_{1} - \dots - x_{100}}\times
\\ & \phantom{\totald{}{S}\int_{0}^{\infty}Aa}\on{P}_{1}\pars{x_{1}}\ldots
\on{P}_{100\,}\pars{x_{100}}\,\dd x_{1}\ldots\dd x_{100}
\\[2mm] & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ldots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\delta\pars{S - x_{1} - \dots - x_{100}}\times
\\ & \phantom{\totald{}{S}\int_{0}^{\infty}Aa}\on{P}_{1}\pars{x_{1}}\ldots
\on{P}_{100\,}\pars{x_{100}}\,\dd x_{1}\ldots\dd x_{100}
\\[2mm] & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ldots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\bracks{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\expo{\ic k\pars{S\ -\ x_{1}\ -\ \dots\ -\ x_{100}\,\,}}\,\,\,\,{\dd k \over 2\pi}}
\times
\\ & \phantom{\totald{}{S}\int_{0}^{\infty}Aa}\on{P}_{1}\pars{x_{1}}\ldots
\on{P}_{100\,}\pars{x_{100}}\,\dd x_{1}\ldots\dd x_{100}
\\[2mm] & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic kS}
\bracks{\prod_{n = 1}^{100}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\on{P}_{n}\pars{x_{n}}\expo{-\ic kx_{n}}\,\,\dd x_{n}}{\dd k \over 2\pi}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{\color{#44f}{%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic kS}
\bracks{\prod_{n = 1}^{100}\pars{p_{n}\expo{-\ic k} + q_{n}}}{\dd k \over 2\pi}}} \\ &
\end{align}
